# How to delete a ms-word document if it contains various phrases with VBA?

Tags: string, vba, loops, while-loop, ms-word

I am very new to VBA and I am aware this contains errors.

In MS-Word developer, I would like to go up one directory, search all *.docx files for multiple strings, if any of the strings exist within the *docx file, I would like to delete the file.

```
Sub loopFiles()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File
Dim fold As Folder
Dim yourfolder As String
Dim UpOneDir As String

Set fold = fso.GetFolder(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

For Each fil In fold.Files

UpOneDir = Left(fil.Path, Len(fil.Path) - Len(fil.Name) - 1 - Len(Split(Left(fil.Path, Len(fil.Path) - Len(fil.Name) - 1), "\")(UBound(Split(Left(fil.Path, Len(fil.Path) - Len(fil.Name) - 1), "\")))))

Sub FindIt()
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "Aircraft Survey","Cc:","UTAS","Inserted in the word document is a pdf file"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            Do While .Execute

            If InStr(1, fil.Text, "Aircraft Survey","Cc:","UTAS","Inserted in the word document is a pdf file") > 0 Then
                Application.Workbook.Open fil.Path
                ActiveWorkbook.Close

            fil.Delete True
        End If
    Loop
End With
End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, `InStr` only allows one text value to be checked at any time - your setup will fail with syntax errors because you are providing 4 strings.  Same with `Selection.Find` - search for a single text string at a time.  Or cook up an interesting regular expression.

Comment: Also, you can't do these `.Find` commands unless you already opened the document.

Comment: If you're using Word, you will find that `Application.Workbook.Open` won't work - that's an Excel VBA command (and it's wrong even in Excel, it would be `Workbooks` not `workbook`, you'd need `Application.Documents.Open`.  Same with `ActiveWorkbook.Close` - Workbook is an Excel object, not Word.  `ActiveDocument.Close` would be the correct command

Comment: You have a `Sub` inside your `Sub` - these should be separate entities that call each other where necessary

Comment: Dave, would you be willing to provide an answer? I could edit the pieces you shared but it would ultimately leave me in the same place I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  You might want to test this by commenting out the `oFile.Delete` and replace it with a `MsgBox oFile.Name` so it doesn't just delete files.  Once you're happy that it's definitely finding the files you require, use the delete command.

```
Option Explicit


Sub loopFiles()
    Dim oFso: Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' create FileSystemObject
    Dim oFolder: Set oFolder = oFso.GetFolder(oFso.GetParentFolderName(ThisDocument.Path))    ' Set folder to the Parent of the folder containing this file
    Dim oFile, oDocument, textVal, bFound
    Dim TextValues: TextValues = Array("Aircraft Survey", "Cc:", "UTAS", "Inserted in the word document is a pdf file") ' create array of terms to check

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If Right(oFile.Name, 5) = ".docx" Then  ' if file is a *.docx
            Set oDocument = Documents.Open(oFile.Path)  ' Open it
            bFound = False                              ' Initialise
            For Each textVal In TextValues  ' check for each text value
                With oDocument.Content.Find
                    .Text = textVal
                    .Forward = True
                    .Execute
                    If .Found = True Then       ' if found then set bFound
                        bFound = True
                        Exit For                ' and exit the loop, no need to keep looking
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            oDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges  ' close file and don't save any changes
            If bFound = True Then               ' If the text was found in the file
                oFile.Delete                    ' delete the file
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following Run-time error: This method or property is not available because the object refers to a protected area of the document. --> while debugging, error starts at .Execute. --> I am not familiar with this error nor how to solve it. If the document is protected in any way, it wouldn't be password protected

Comment: Sorry, without knowing more about the document I can't help further. I checked and this code definitely works on normal .docx files. If the files you are working with contain protected ranges or content maybe that's what's causing the problem? Without the document to hand I can't say. Have you tried googling the error message?

Comment: So I troubleshooted and found all the files causing errors, they are forms that only allow certain portions to be edited. I would still like to search them for a string and delete if exists. The strings can be found within the doc using ctrl+f but not edited. Any ideas? The code works great for all other files though!